# How can I add the Windows 8 style copy / move dialog box (detailed view with a real-time throughput graph) in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer

Windows 8 [added](http://www.askvg.com/microsoft-official-video-shows-improved-file-management-ui-copy-move-rename-delete-in-windows-8/) a detailed view with a real-time throughput graph to the copy / move dialog box ([video](http://helpdesktv.ca/windows/the-new-copymove-dialog-box-in-windows-8/)):

[image]

Is there anyway to add such a graph in Windows 7?

Comment: From the screenshots I could find on Internet, none of them seems to have any real-time graph.

Comment: Only way that works from windows 7 is to open DVD tray, insert W8 DVD, reboot and follow on screen instructions.